# Monkeytalk JS getting length of table

Tags: javascript, monkey-testing

I have a table I need to get the number of rows on. 
I'm trying this

```
this.app.table("#1").length
```

but it returns 0 or 1. I'm not very familiar with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.app.table("#1").get("x", "size");
```

Thats what someone in the monkeytalk-forum said and it is working! :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.app.table("#1")[0].rows.length
```

Comment: @Chris I cant find any results on google for `"moneytalk" "javascript"` and `Your search - "monerytalkjs" - did not match any documents.` Can you link to the projects source code or documentation or website?

Comment: http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation this is the docs for monkey talk. its a testing IDE that uses JS

Comment: @Chris here's the docs http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-spec/javascript/javascript-api but it doesn't contain any method to retrieve what you want so I need to view the source code. Can you tell where can I download the source code? NVM I found it but it requires a password....